# Does work done in Application onCreate() persist after app is backgrounded?

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-background

My app does some recurring work in both the foreground and background. In the background, the work can be kicked off by either a BroadcastReceiver or a WorkManager task. Before this work is done, however, some one-time setup needs to be done.

Is my Application's `onCreate()` the right place to do this one-time setup? Specifically:

- Will this setup persist once the app is backgrounded and eventually enters idle state?
- If my app is kicked off because the system is low on memory, will `onCreate()` get called the next time my background task is started (by a BroadcastReceiver or as a scheduled WorkManager task), hence setting up my app properly again?
- When the background work is started from a BroadcastReceiver listening to `BOOT_COMPLETED`, will `onCreate()` get called in the background even if the user hasn't explicitly started the app yet?

Answer (score 0):

the application has also life cycle so **oncreate** so if you close app from home button or if system need memory will go to **ondestroy** function so oncreate is bad choice so u can use **service** that work in background and push local android notification to notify user and when click on it will open app once again

Comment: `if system need memory will go to ondestroy function` no it won't `so oncreate is bad choice` no it's not. Although you do need a `BroadcastReceiver` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` with `BOOT_COMPLETED`.